# How do I get the address from a signature?

Tags: addresses, signature, ecdsa

As stated in the question, I have the v, r and s values of a signature given and am trying to find the belonging address. All questions similar to this solved it by either using a solidity smart contract or web.js. Is there a way to do this without using these two resources, and preferably, any other external resources?

Comment: You will need at least a library that implements Elliptic Curve Cryptography and Keccak-256 hashing function. Then it is matter to implement ECDSA recover algorithm from Ethereum Yellow Paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any package that supports eliptic curve will do as log as you have: s,v,r, and the message. The recovery will return the publickey and the address is the first 20 bytes of the hash of the public key.

See this answer for more details on how the recovery is done and how the values s,r, and v are used. (https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38351/ecdsa-v-r-s-what-is-v)

Hope this helps